# VS Code select multiple lines by dragging -> multiple cursor

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been using Sublime for many years and now I want to try VS Code.
In Sublime, I could have had multiple cursors at the end of each line by dragging multiple lines of code and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. But it seems in VS Code it just sends the cursor to the end of selected lines.

I know I could use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+`click` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>arrow</kbd> to do similar act but I really love that I could just drag and have multiple cursors.

Is it possible to do the same thing in VS Code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>  puts a cursor at the end of each selected line.

Command is :  `editor.action.insertCursorAtEndOfEachLineSelected`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> is already bound to another command: `command:editor.action.selectHighlights`

But you could rebind either one if you wanted to or just learn <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>.

---

Also, you can try <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>drag</kbd> if you still want those lines selected (hit right/end to unselect but leave cursors at end of each line.

Answer (score 9):

In my case on Ubuntu, I have to hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> based on `editor.multiCursorModifier` in the setting, and then click on the places where I wanted to have cursor there. Also, I could select multiple lines by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or just <kbd>Alt</kbd> and dragging mouse. This is available only when I set `editor.multiCursorModifier` to `ctrlCmd` in the settings or by adding the following line to `settings.json`.

```
    "editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd"
```

Comment: This can now be toggled from the VS Code "Selection" menu!